# Custom cleaning a vector of strings using janitor::make_clean_names()

Tags: r, string, janitor

I have a vector that contains column names of a data frame. I want to clean up those strings.

```r
vec_of_names <- c("FIRST_column", 
                  "another-column", 
                  "ALLCAPS-column", 
                  "cOLumn-with___specialsuffix", 
                  "blah#4-column",
                  "ANOTHER_EXAMPLE___specialsuffix",
                  "THIS_IS-Misleading_specialsuffix")
```

I specifically want to use `janitor::make_clean_names()` for this cleanup.

```r
janitor::make_clean_names(vec_of_names)

[1] "first_column"                     "another_column"                  
[3] "allcaps_column"                   "c_o_lumn_with_specialsuffix"     
[5] "blah_number_4_column"             "another_example_specialsuffix"   
[7] "this_is_misleading_specialsuffix"
```

**However,** I want to apply the following rule:

1. When the string ends with `___specialsuffix` (i.e., 3 underscores and "specialsuffix"),

   - clean with `janitor::make_clean_names()` only the part BEFORE `___specialsuffix` 
      (meaning, the value returned from `strsplit(x, "___specialsuffix")`).
   - then keep the cleaned string pasted back to `___specialsuffix`.
2. Otherwise, if the string doesn't end with `___specialsuffix`, then clean it regularly using `janitor::make_clean_names()` over the entire string.

**Desired output** will therefore be:

```r
[1] "first_column"                     "another_column"                  
[3] "allcaps_column"                   "c_o_lumn_with___specialsuffix"     ## elements [4] and [6]
[5] "blah_number_4_column"             "another_example___specialsuffix"   ## were handled according to rule #1
[7] "this_is_misleading_specialsuffix"                                     ## outlined above
```

Thanks a lot for any idea!

Comment: Does the answer achieve what you need? Feel free to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: just finished verifying it was working. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vec_of_names <- c("FIRST_column", 
                  "another-column", 
                  "ALLCAPS-column", 
                  "cOLumn-with___specialsuffix", 
                  "blah#4-column",
                  "ANOTHER_EXAMPLE___specialsuffix",
                  "THIS_IS-Misleading_specialsuffix")


library(tidyverse)

suffix <- vec_of_names %>% str_extract(pattern = "___specialsuffix$") %>% replace_na("")
cleaned_without_suffix <- vec_of_names %>% str_remove("___specialsuffix$") %>% janitor::make_clean_names()


output <- paste0(cleaned_without_suffix, suffix)
```